# what is difference between gcc version and Xcode gcc version?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

This maybe a little silly question but I am very confused

executing pkgutil in shell I get

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 6.1.1.0.1.1416017670
```

the above tells me version 6.1

and gcc version in shell tells

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

This says LLVM version 6.0 ,
Can anyone explains what the above versions are telling are which version of what !!

Comment: [Using gcc not llvm-gcc with Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8707367/289086): "As of Xcode 4.2 in Lion, Apple no longer ships its previous version of gcc-4.2, which was in Xcode 4.1 and earlier versions. It now only ships llvm-gcc (gcc front-end with llvm code backend) and clang (clang front-end with llvm backend)."

Comment: I am on OSx Mavericks .

Comment: the thing is, gcc isn't gcc on a mac and hasn't been for a very long time. Unless you take special steps to do otherwise, invoking gcc on a mac is actually clang/llvm running in a mode that is compatible with gcc's options.

Comment: duh, so Apple did it to support API that are specifically meant for OSx development ?

Comment: clang is intended for toolchain use (making it ideal for use in xcode). (See [Is there a way to use gcc as a library?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/189949/40980)) Apple has decided to only expend effort to support one open source compiler, and an open source compiler that is trivially compatible with integration on their systems (rather than the GPL v3 of gcc).  See also [Why is FreeBSD deprecating GCC in favor of Clang/LLVM?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49970/46212) though note that is a few years out of date (llvm has come a quite a ways since then).